# Verify that generic type implements a certain interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IView<TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}

public interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

I would like to make sure that the generic `TViewModel` is always a class that implements interface `IViewModel`. I could do the following:

```
public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

But then I would not have access to all the properties and methods of the specific class of `ViewModel`.

How can I make sure that `TViewModel` is always a class that implements interface `IViewModel`?

Comment: `where TViewModel : IViewModel`? But that's just basic [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: I must have missed that page... Sorry for the basic question. If you would like to make it an answer, I would mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a generic type constraint using the [`where` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

```
public interface IView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : IViewModel
{
    TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```